# Querying Google Street View API URL ignores API restrictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

I have generated an API key to consume the JS Maps API and added a few restrictions such as:

```
*.mysite.com
mysite.com/events/*
```

[image: GCP API config]

Now, if I include the script in a page that is served from a domain that is not `mysite.com` I see:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: https://null.someotherdomain.com/
```

**This is all ok**.

Now, if I request locally a Google APIs URL like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988353&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=MY_API_KEY

As long as `MY_API_KEY` exists, I do get a valid response, via either a curl or by using a browser.
Shouldn't this content be prevented from rendering at all since the key is meant to serve only requests coming from `mysite.com`?

I also tried restricting the key even more and removing the access to the JS Maps api and it still returns a Street View image.
I might be missing something entirely obvious here, can anyone shed some light?

*EDIT*

Another restriction that I put in place is by API:

[image]

As you can see, the Street View API is explicitly disabled

[image]

Comment: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview` is **not** the JS API you mentioned in your question. It is the Street View Static API, a web service.

Comment: You cannot restrict access to web services with HTTP Referrers. You need to use IP address restrictions. See https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table

Comment: @MrUpsidown yes, that's the Street View Static API, but I explicitly disabled it (I added an EDIT to my question with screenshots) so I would expect that be excluded? Sorry if I'm not making sense. Btw, thanks a lot for chiming in.

Comment: Are you sure you are on the right project / key? If yes then maybe try generating a new key.

Comment: I was on the right project and the key was newly generated (yesterday). After reading your last comment I generated again a new one with the same configuration and - of course - now it works and it blocks that request. This doesn't make a lot of sense, but at least it works now and it's a relief. Thanks so much for replying, if you'd like to post your comments as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I haven't experienced this myself but apparently sometimes it takes time to enable/disable an API or set restrictions to a key or it might simply fail. In this case, generating a new key seems the most appropriate action to take.